# Programatically get the web page content

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

I would like to know whether WinInet or WinHttp will get webpage contents quickly or is there any other quicker method for getting webpage content (less than 1 sec).

The programming environment which I am using is VC++

Comment: The biggest factor in getting a webpage quickly is the pipe your computer is connected to. The execution time on the client is miniscule in comparison, even with a homebrew page fetcher coded in sockets.

Comment: @monoxide - You should make that your answer. It's right, so it should get accepted, and I'd vote you up.

Comment: You can also use libcurl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by the commenters, Internet doesn't guarantee load times.

As for the specific API, I'd use [XMLHTTPRequest COM object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759148(VS.85).aspx) instead of WinInet or WinHttp.

P.S. Don't forget to call CoInitialize.